# initialize fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I only know how to add fragment and remove.
also show and hide.

I just want to initialize fragment.

```
onCreate {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.top_container, new AuthProgressDialog(), AuthProgressDialog.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide( getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AuthProgressDialog.class.getSimpleName()) ).commit();
}
```

This is bad code, isn't it?

If you have any idea, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Just instantiating your fragment class should initialize it, except the `onCreate` and other lifecycle methods are called only after adding or replacing with the transaction

Answer (score 1):

This is sample method which you can define inside your FragmentActivity and call from any of the fragment. in which if you want to allowing adding to backstack than just remove comment line from transaction.addToBackStack("back"); and check popup backstack as per your requirement inside FragmentActivity.

```
  public void displayView(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FormFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        if (position != 0)
            // transaction.addToBackStack("back");
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_ll_container, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment fraggy = new DummyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fraggy);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```